# Flask: How do I get POST to return data?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm currently working creating some communication between JS and Python using AJAX and Flask. To start off, the file structure is as follows:

```
-datacenters
   -app.py
   -index.html
   -index.js
```

I want to be able to send data back to index.html and display it without refreshing the page. The html invokes index.js, where I have used jQuery to perform an ajax POST to the locally running app.py.

**index.js**

```
function postData() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/return_data/",
      success: function(resp) {
        alert(resp.data)
      }
  })
}
```

It's to my understanding that this function, when called, should access `return_data` located in app.py. I think it's doing so.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/Users/dcs/datacenters')
app.config['EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING'] = True

.......

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/return_data/', methods=['POST'])
def return_data():
    values = [1, 2, 3]
    return jsonify({'data': render_template('index.html', values=values)})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Each time `postData` is called, the output shown in app.py is:

```
[2019-12-31 10:18:25,890] INFO in debughelpers: Locating template "index.html":
    1: trying loader of application "__main__"
       class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
       encoding: 'utf-8'
       followlinks: False
       searchpath:
         - /Users/dcs/datacenters
       -> found ('/Users/dcs/datacenters/index.html')
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2019 10:18:25] "POST /return_data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

So the receiving part is fine, since it's giving 200. I know `values` is not used, I am simply trying to trigger an alert at this point before I move forward with any data manipulation.

Comment: So what is your question? What did you expect to happen and doesn't happen?

Comment: I'm not getting the alert that's specified in the success part of the ajax function. On the python side, it seems fine, there is just no response back on the html page.

Comment: You are missing a `dataType: 'json',` line in your `$.ajax({...})` call.

Comment: You'll have a javascript error in your browser console.

Comment: That had not become a problem yet, although I'm sure it would have. On further inspection I found it to be a CORS issue as they are running on different domains.

Comment: Right, that wasn't part of your MCVE, so impossible for us to determine.